# ReferenceError saving data to mongodb using mongoose in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save to a user collection in mongodb using mongoose and I'm getting the following

**Error:**        `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'user' before initialization`.

```
const user = mongoose.model("users");

try {
        const user = await new user({
          googleId: profile.id,
          name: profile.displayName,
          email: profile.emails[0].values
        }).save();

        done(null, user);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error " + err);
      }
    }
```

Here is my user.js file:

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 const { Schema } = mongoose;

 const userSchema = new Schema({
     googleId: String,
     name: String,
     email: String
 });

 mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

Comment: In your first code snippet, you need to import the `users` object form `user.js` model file. Can you please share the whole codebase of the first code snippet and also the folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

You have to export your model schema :
user.js

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

// User Schema
let userSchema  = mongoose.Schema({
     googleId: String,
     name: String,
     email: String
});

let User = module.exports = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

index.js

```
// User model must be in same directory
const User = mongoose.model("users");

const user = new User();
//add model proporties
user.googleId = profile.id;
user.name = profile.displayName;
user.email = profile.emails[0].values;
//save user to db
user.save(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(err.message);
      return;
    }
    res.send('success');
    return;
});
```

Comment: I had a small typo at my code snippet , try again if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help I got the following solution from two users on discord: @Lumeey & @Korbook:

1. model user.js was changed to the following :

   ```
   const mongoose = require("mongoose");
   const { Schema } = mongoose;

   const userSchema = new Schema({
     googleId: String,
     name: String,
     email: String
    });

   module.exports = mongoose.model("Users", userSchema);
   ```
2. In my passport.js  :

   ```
   const User = require("../models/user");

   try {
       const user = await User.create({
        googleId: profile.id,
        name: profile.displayName,
        email: profile.emails[0].value
      });

      done(null, user);
   } catch (err) {
      console.log("error " + err);

   }
   ```